# org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInterceptor not found despite being in Classpath - Spring + JBoss AS 7

Tags: hibernate, spring, classnotfoundexception, jboss7.x

I am trying to use Java Persistence API (JPA) with Spring in a JSF 2.0 application with Hibernate 3 on JBoss Application Server 7 Web Profile. Upon startup, I get the following error:

```
21:24:12,880 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (MSC service thread 1-4) Failed to define class org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateInterceptor in Module "deployment.PlayingDatabase.war:main" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/HibernateInterceptor (Module "deployment.PlayingDatabase.war:main" from Service Module Loader)
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:401)
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:261)
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:76)
at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:588)
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:183)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:358)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:307)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:101)
at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:257) [org.springframework.core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:408) [org.springframework.beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1282) [org.springframework.beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1253) [org.springframework.beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576) [org.springframework.beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1330) [org.springframework.beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:317) [org.springframework.beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:396) [org.springframework.beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:594) [org.springframework.context-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:407) [org.springframework.context-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:282) [org.springframework.web-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:204) [org.springframework.web-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47) [org.springframework.web-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3368) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.1.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3821) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:70) [jboss-as-web-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.1.Final]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1765)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ClearTCCLTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2291)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [:1.6.0_22]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [:1.6.0_22]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679) [:1.6.0_22]

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aopalliance/intercept/MethodInterceptor
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [:1.6.0_22]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634) [:1.6.0_22]
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) [:1.6.0_22]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:397)
... 28 more

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInterceptor from [Module "deployment.PlayingDatabase.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:191)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:358)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:330)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:330)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:307)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:101)
... 32 more
```

I have researched that I need the file aopalliance-1.0.jar. I do. My classpath contains the file noted here, I took it from the "required" folder in the Hibernate 3. I added it to the Java Build Path in Eclipse. The error persists. Similarly, the MySQL driver in the build path is not found.

```
21:24:12,970 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/PlayingDatabase]] (MSC service thread 1-4) Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/web-application-config.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'driverClassName' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1361) [org.springframework.beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086) [org.springframework.beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) [org.springframework.beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456) [org.springframework.beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293) [org.springframework.beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) [org.springframework.beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290) [org.springframework.beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192) [org.springframework.beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585) [org.springframework.beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895) [org.springframework.context-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425) [org.springframework.context-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:282) [org.springframework.web-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:204) [org.springframework.web-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47) [org.springframework.web-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3368) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.1.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3821) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:70) [jboss-as-web-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.1.Final]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1765)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ClearTCCLTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2291)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [:1.6.0_22]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [:1.6.0_22]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679) [:1.6.0_22]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'driverClassName' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver]
at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:102) [org.springframework.beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:]
at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:58) [org.springframework.beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1358) [org.springframework.beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:]
... 21 more
```

I am using Eclipse Indigo on Kubuntu 11.04. The server and the workspace are both in my home partition, I don't see a rights issue here.

My full list of jars:

```
antlr-2.7.6.jar
**aopalliance-1.0.jar**
commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar
commons-beanutils-1.8.3-javadoc.jar
commons-beanutils-1.8.3-sources.jar
commons-beanutils-bean-collections-1.8.3.jar
commons-beanutils-core-1.8.3.jar
commons-collections-3.1.jar
commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
commons-collections-3.2.1-javadoc.jar
commons-collections-3.2.1-sources.jar
commons-collections-testframework-3.2.1.jar
commons-digester-2.1.jar
commons-digester-2.1-javadoc.jar
commons-digester-2.1-sources.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1-javadoc.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1-sources.jar
commons-logging-adapters-1.1.1.jar
commons-logging-api-1.1.1.jar
commons-logging-tests.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
hibernate3.jar
hibernate-testing.jar
hibernate-validator-4.2.0.Final.jar
hibernate-validator-annotation-processor-4.2.0.Final.jar
javassist-3.12.0.GA.jar
jta-1.1.jar
mysql-connector-java-5.1.17-bin.jar
org.springframework.aop-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.asm-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.aspects-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.context-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.context.support-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.expression-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.instrument-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.instrument.tomcat-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.jdbc-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.jms-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.orm-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.oxm-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.test-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.transaction-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.web-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.web.portlet-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.web.servlet-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.web.struts-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
primefaces-2.2.1.jar
slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar
```

My web.xml:

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>PlayingDatabase</display-name>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/web-application-config.xml </param-value>
  </context-param>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>500000</session-timeout>
  </session-config>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

web-application-config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" id="dataSource"
        p:driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" p:password="" p:url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/"
        p:username=""> </bean>
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean"
        p:dataSource-ref="dataSource">
        <property name="hibernateProperties">   
          <value>
            hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
            hibernate.show_sql=true
            hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
          </value>
        </property>
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
          <list>
            <!-- -->
          </list>
        </property>
     </bean>

     <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

</beans>
```

Comment: Besides what @duffymo said, you need to make sure that JBoss is preferring your app's libs over its own to prevent versioning/dependency issues, which can also cause `CNFE`s. I sure hope you're using Maven (or equivalent) to manage your dependencies, though.

Comment: "I added it to the Java Build Path in Eclipse" - but you're having problems with JBoss, not Eclipse. How have you added it to JBoss class path?

Answer (score 1):

Well i would recommend you to change the version of your Spring mvc because `Spring 3.0` is not supporting `Hibernate 4.2` you can read the manual in that they have maintain this as Issue means BUG. so i would like to suggest you that switch spring version to `Spring 3.1.1` or above and even `Spring 3.2` will be better. and ya then change your code like this.

```
 <bean id="sessionFactory"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
            p:dataSource-ref="dataSource">
            <property name="hibernateProperties">   
              <value>
                hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
                hibernate.show_sql=true
                hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
              </value>
            </property>
            <property name="annotatedClasses">
              <list>
                annoted Classes.
              </list>
            </property>
         </bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

> My classpath contains the file noted here

If you get a `ClassNotFoundException`, it means the JAR isn't in the `CLASSPATH`.  You aren't doing it properly.  You need to lose the mindset that says "I did everything right" and figure out what you did wrong.

Comment: What does it take to be in the classpath? In Eclipse, I rightclick on my project, select "Build Path" and click "Configure Build Path". The project properties open and in the selection "Java Build Path", the tab "libraries" does contain Aopalliance-1.0.jar. I click on the tab "Order and Export" and rearrange the order so that aopalliance-1.0.jar is the very first file in line of the order (at the top). It is not ticked in the "order and export" list. What does ticking anything in this list do? Currently only my source folder has a half tick in it, from what I can make out.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding it in your build path via Eclipse build config, add it directly in your WEB-INF/lib/  folder.